# is there a way to convert a json object to json l file

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have an array of objects. I need to convert it in .jsonl format and send it as response using node in a lambda function 
i have been trying to change it as a string and add '\n' to make it a new line but it didn't work

Comment: could you post sample data and expected format?

Comment: Please clarify. You can put an array of objects in JSON format all on one line and it's a valid single-record JSONL file. If you want each item of the array to be a separate line/record, just convert each element to a string individually and join the resulting strings together with newlines.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlines

Comment: You should probably post that as an answer instead of a comment, @user120242.

Comment: the package posted above is 6 years old, don't use it. same for https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-jsonl - no updates for 5 years. use the top answer from below, it is that simple.

Answer (score 15):

Simple code to generate jsonlines.  jsonlines is really just a bunch of one-line JSON objects stringified and concatenated with newlines between them.  That's it.
The other issue you will need to deal with is escaping unicode, so when you write to a file, you must use UTF-8 encoding.

repl.it demo using jsonlines npm library: https://repl.it/repls/AngelicGratefulMoto

Simple plain JS demo:

```js
data = [{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' }]

console.log(
data.map(x=>JSON.stringify(x)).join('\n')
)
```

Comment: the link https://replit.com/repls/AngelicGratefulMoto which is repl.it demo using jsonlines npm library is dead

Answer (score -1):

Approaches to resolve the issue for larger amount of data conversion from [`.json`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) to [`.jsonl`](https://jsonlines.org/) :

1. Monkey patching trial before implementing @user120242's answer failed due to presence of `{` , `}`, `[`, `]` in the data

   ```js
   const sampleData = [{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' }]

   console.log(JSON.stringify(sampleData).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replaceAll('},{', '}\n{'));
   ```
2. `@user120242`'s answer works (I wanted a solution that was free from any external libraries or packages as far as possible) for smaller data and is indeed a clean solution which worked for me upto data which was `~100 MB` of `array of objects`, beyond that it fails (my solution was working in `node.js v14.1.0` being executed by `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88` using [`DockerOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#module-airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker) in [`airflow v2.0.1`](https://airflow.apache.org/) upto data which was `~100 MB` of `array of objects` and it was failing miserably for data in the range of `~750 MB` of `array of objects` with this issue - [JSON.stringify throws RangeError: Invalid string length for huge objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29175877/3152654))
3. Trail for similar solution to https://dev.to/madhunimmo/json-stringify-rangeerror-invalid-string-length-3977 for converting [`.json`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) to [`.jsonl`](https://jsonlines.org/) didn't work with same issue as above - [JSON.stringify throws RangeError: Invalid string length for huge objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29175877/3152654)
4. Implementing `for...of` from [`@Bergi`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/3152654) -  [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/3152654) worked out with great performance (my implementation was working in `node.js v14.1.0` being executed by `Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88` using [`DockerOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#module-airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker) in [`airflow v2.0.1`](https://airflow.apache.org/) upto data which was `~750 MB` of `array of objects`)

```js
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const writeToFile = async () => {
    const dataArray = [{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' },{ jsonlines: 'is awesome' }];
    for (const dataObject of dataArray) {
        await fsPromises.appendFile( "out.jsonl" , JSON.stringify(dataObject) + "\n");
    }
}
```

P.S. : You'll face [Node JS Process out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37514351/3152654) with larger data (typically `>100 MB`)if you haven't already provided extra memory above the default to `node.js v14.1.0`, the following worked out for usage inside `Dockerfile` (replace `6144` with the amount of memory in `MB` which you want to allocate)

```
CMD node --max-old-space-size=6144 app.js
```